# Any explaination for Android android.content.SyncManager?

Tags: android, synchronization

I've be searching around to find out how the Android Sync mechanism works.

Speciallfy for the ContentResolver.addPeriodSync() method.

who is calling the sync operation frequently?

I came across with the andorid.content.SyncMananger, which seems to be the one doing this from Android framework.

But I couldn't find any document for the SyncManager except the Source Code.

Answer (score 0):

All Apps are able to call this method.

It is mostly used when an account is created, on Apps that use SyncAdapters. This is what most Apps will use to keep their data current. addPeriodicSync lets you tell Android that a SyncAdapter needs to run a sync operation repeatedly, with a set period.

The synchronization mechanism isn't very well documented, but if you google SyncAdapter you should find enough details.

Please see SyncAdapter:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.html